# When I scroll a listview with a custom adapter too fast up and down, getView() starts behaving oddly. Why?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter

I have a listview with a custom arrayadapter that handles about 15 strings. The style of each row alternates (between labels and values for those labels--for example row 1 could be "email address" and row 2 would be the actual email address). I'm changing the style of each row to alternate like this in the arrayadapter's getView() method. So if the item at the current position is a label, I'll change the styling from the default row style (which is what the values have applied to them). When the listview first loads, the styling is perfect and just how I want it to be. If I scroll the list slowly up or down, it stays that way. However, if I scroll the list fast up and down, the styling of the value rows starts changing to that of the label ones until all of the rows have the styling of a label row. Does anyone know why this would be happening? I've used custom adapters on other listviews in the app with no problems like this.

Edit: Found out that it also changes all of the rows to the label styling on portrait->landscape orientation changes. Doesn't do this on landscape->portrait changes. Below is the adapter I'm using. Am I missing something?

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private TextView text = null;
private String item = null;

public DetailsAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    text = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    item = getItem(position);
    if (item.equals("Name") || item.equals("Mobile") || item.equals("Home") || item.equals("Email") || item.equals("Address")) {
        text.setBackgroundColor(0xFF575757);
        text.setTextSize(15);
        text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        text.setPadding(8, 5, 0, 5);
    } else {
        text.setPadding(15, 15, 0, 15);
    }
    return text;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    item = getItem(position);
    if (item.equals("Name") || item.equals("Mobile") || item.equals("Home") || item.equals("Email") || item.equals("Address")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your getView code?

Comment: Initially how many rows will be presented  when listview is loaded. Creating a view for a row using customadapter's getview method is somewhat highly memory intensive task. This is the reason for jumbled rendering of your labels.

Write glimpses of your code.. Might be you get a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android reuses views fairly aggressively, and it is quite possible that a view that was used as an email address row gets reused on a row that's supposed to display a label, and vice-versa.

As a result, you cannot rely on "default" values. Set your padding, typeface, text size and background color in all cases:

```
if (item.equals("Name") || item.equals("Mobile") || item.equals("Home") || item.equals("Email") || item.equals("Address")) {
    text.setBackgroundColor(0xFF575757);
    text.setTextSize(15);
    text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    text.setPadding(8, 5, 0, 5);
} else {
    text.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_BACKGROUND);
    text.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
    text.setTypeface(null, DEFAULT_TYPEFACE);
    text.setPadding(15, 15, 0, 15);
}
```

Comment: "Aggressive" is an accurate term, I'd say!  I've recently been bitten by this bug - which I would call it, in Android.  It makes sense for them to re-use the View going off-screen as a View coming on-screen, but a developer who has reformatted rows in getView() can't be expected to know this!  Maybe ArrayAdapter or SimpleAdapter were not meant for that, however.

Comment: So +1 on Marius's comment!  One thing I would suggest is to make "saveFormat()" and "restoreFormat()" methods to retain the initial values of the row (the "defaults" that Marius is referring to).  This will ease future maintenance, as the row format will always default to one place in the XML.

Comment: What I was trying to do was this: reformat certain rows (set the first TextView "cell" to LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT) to look like "headings" for the rows below them -- similar to Categories in a PreferenceGroup, but I was seeing the "headings" appear in random places when swiping to scroll, especially quickly.  Following the above suggestions fixed everything and made operation solid!

Answer (score 4):

Don't need to do anything. I too faced the same problem and solved it like this:

Just inside the getView method add a first line

```
convertView=null;
```

It wont redraw the view immediately destroyed but instead would create new ones each time based on your logic (even odd or whatever)

Comment: This solved the problem for me but made the listview incredibly laggy.

Comment: Seems to me this should be the correct answer.  Mine didn't lag (it's not really that complicated, though).